# Hex addition with some limitations

Tags: python-3.x, hex

I'm trying to write a function which will take two hex strings and return their sum in hex value.
Now, I'm not allowed to use "int()" or ".decode" or import any modulo for that matter but make it in the old fashion way of summing each digit (like when we were kids)
the problem is I have no idea how to add two string values as hex values
like if the numbers are "15b" and "ba5" so I want to "put" them like
 15b
+

ba5

but now how do I make python know know what is "b"+"5".

any ideas? suggestions?
thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python does know what `"b" + "5"` is, it's `"b5"`!

To map those hex characters to integers, you could use a dictionary:

```
hexmap = {"1": 1, ..., "a": 10, ...}
```

To work through all the numbers, remember that the indices of the reversed string are powers of 16:

```
decimal = sum(16**i * hexmap(s) for i, s in enumerate(reversed(hexstring)))
```

You can then add the two integers together. This is much easier than trying to deal with carrying the extra from adding e.g. `b + 9`.

Comment: it does easier, but we are supposed to do it the hard way. the instructions clearly said to convert each number individually and using loops evaluating the sum- the same way we have here:
http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/66714.html

if the instructions were different I could do it much faster already

Comment: You can still use `hexmap` to define e.g. `"b"` and `"5"`, but you will have to deal with the carried amount at each step.